# How to throw an exception in on error part of reactive Spring WebClient call?

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-webclient, spring-reactive, spring-reactor

I would like the following method to throw a custom exception if an error occurs:

```
@Service
public class MyClass {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public MatcherClient(@Value("${my.url}") final String myUrl) {
        this.webClient = WebClient.create(myUrl);
    }

    public void sendAsync(String request) {

        Mono<MyCustomResponse> result = webClient.post()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
            .retrieve()
            .doOnError(throwable -> throw new CustomException(throwable.getMessage()))
            .subscribe(response -> log.info(response));

    }

}
```

I have also set up a unit test expecting the CustomException to be thrown. Unfortunately the test fails and the Exception is kind of wrapped into a Mono object. Here also the test code for reference:

```
@Test(expected = CustomException.class)
public void testSendAsyncRethrowingException() {
    MockResponse mockResponse = new MockResponse()
        .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        .setResponseCode(500).setBody("Server error");
    mockWebServer.enqueue(mockResponse);

    matcherService.matchAsync(track);
}
```

I'm using the [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) to mock an error in the test.

So, how should I implement the doOnError or onError part if the call in order to make my method really to throw an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `doOnError` I swiched to subscribe method accepting also an error consumer:

```
Mono<MyCustomResponse> result = webClient.post()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
            .retrieve()
            .subscribe(response -> log.info(response),
                       throwable -> throw new CustomException(throwable.getMessage()));
```

This documentation helps a lot: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#_error_handling_operators

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise to expose a reactive API that returns the `Mono<Void>` from the webclient, especially if you name your method "sendAsync". It's not async if you have to block for the call to return/fail. If you want to provide a `sendSync()` alternative, you can always make it call `sendAsync().block()`.

For the conversion of exception, you can use the dedicated `onErrorMap` operator.

For the test, the thing is, you can't 100% test asynchronous code with purely imperative and synchronous constructs (like JUnit's `Test(expected=?)` annotation). (although *some* reactive operator don't induce parallelism so this kind of test can *sometimes* work).

You can also use `.block()` here (testing is one of the rare occurrences where this is unlikely to be problematic).

But if I were you I'd get in the habit of using `StepVerifier` from `reactor-test`. To give an example that sums up my recommendations:

```
@Service
public class MyClass {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public MatcherClient(@Value("${my.url}") final String myUrl) {
        this.webClient = WebClient.create(myUrl);
    }

    public Mono<MyCustomResponse> sendAsync(String request) {
        return webClient.post()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(request))
            .retrieve()
            .onErrorMap(throwable -> new CustomException(throwable.getMessage()))
            //if you really need to hardcode that logging
            //(can also be done by users who decide to subscribe or further add operators)
            .doOnNext(response -> log.info(response));
    }
}
```

and the test:

```
@Test(expected = CustomException.class)
public void testSendAsyncRethrowingException() {
    MockResponse mockResponse = new MockResponse()
        .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        .setResponseCode(500).setBody("Server error");
    mockWebServer.enqueue(mockResponse);

    //Monos are generally lazy, so the code below doesn't trigger any HTTP request yet
    Mono<MyCustomResponse> underTest = matcherService.matchAsync(track);

    StepVerifier.create(underTest)
    .expectErrorSatisfies(t -> assertThat(t).isInstanceOf(CustomException.class)
        .hasMessage(throwable.getMessage())
    )
    .verify(); //this triggers the Mono, compares the
               //signals to the expectations/assertions and wait for mono's completion

}
```

Comment: Generally that would be an approach if I would start to implement an application from scratch. Unfortunately, I have to deal with running system strictly relying on a custom business exception to be thrown in curtain cases (and creating some reports in catch blocks), so I just have to support the old test with @Test(expected=...). Also the documentation of the reactor project suggests this implementation as a valid option. So thank you for your answer, but this doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: The `expected` attribute of the `@Test` annotation is only required with _JUnit 4_ and is not supported by _JUnit 5_

Answer (score 1):

> **The retrieve() method in WebClient throws a WebClientResponseException
> whenever a response with status code 4xx or 5xx is received.**

**1. You can customize the exception using the onStatus() method**

```
public Mono<JSONObject> listGithubRepositories() {
 return webClient.get()
        .uri(URL)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, clientResponse ->
            Mono.error(new MyCustomClientException())
        )
        .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, clientResponse ->
            Mono.error(new MyCustomServerException())
        )
        .bodyToMono(JSONObject.class);
}
```

**2. Throw the custom exception by checking the response status**

```
   Mono<Object> result = webClient.get().uri(URL).exchange().log().flatMap(entity -> {
        HttpStatus statusCode = entity.statusCode();
        if (statusCode.is4xxClientError() || statusCode.is5xxServerError())
        {
            return Mono.error(new Exception(statusCode.toString()));
        }
        return Mono.just(entity);
    }).flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(JSONObject.class))
```

**Reference:** https://www.callicoder.com/spring-5-reactive-webclient-webtestclient-examples/